# outputting a featured image rather than a link to a featured image

Tags: php, wordpress

In the past, I used this custom function to create an image carousel on my WordPress blog with Thesis theme

```
function top_carousel() {

      echo '<div id="topcarousel">';
       $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
          'category_name'=>'featured',
          'orderby'=>'date',
          'order'=>'DESC',
          'showposts'=>'4'
      ));

      while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();
          $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID;
          $post_image = thesis_post_image_info('thumb');
          echo '<div class="carouselu">';
              echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . $post_image['output'] . '<br />' . get_the_title() . '</a>';  
          echo '</div>';

      echo '<div style="clear:both"></div>';
      echo '</div>';

}
add_action('thesis_hook_before_content_box', 'top_carousel');
```

It has been a while since I used the code, and, having recently setup a new WordPress blog, I discovered it doesn't work anymore, in that the image isn't getting displayed with the link to the post.

Someone suggested to me that this might be because I'm using featured images in my new WordPress blog. Following that tip and looking [at the code on the WordPress code](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail), I changed part of the custom function above to look like this

```
$post_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'small');

          echo '<div class="carouselu">';
              echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . $post_image[0] . '<br />' . get_the_title() . '</a>';  
           echo '</div>';
```

This results in a little progress. Now a link to the image appears above the headline, rather than the actual image. For example,

```
http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Screen-Shot-2013-12-27-at-9.37.49-AM.png
```

How do I get the image to show, rather than just a link to where the image is uploaded?

Update

Using the first answer to this post, I tried this code unsuccessfully

```
  $post_image =  get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'small');

          echo '<div class="carouselu">';

              echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . $post_image['output'] . '<br />' . get_the_title() . '</a>';  

          echo '</div>';
```

I also tried this unsuccessfully

```
 $post_image =  wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'small'));

  echo '<div class="carouselu">';

              echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . $post_image['output'] . '<br />' . get_the_title() . '</a>';  

          echo '</div>';
```

Neither of those solutions output anything, whereas my attempt at least output a link to the uploaded image. Am I using the function incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the function `get_the_post_thumbnail`, refering to the doc : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail

**Usage**:

```
 <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $size, $attr ); ?>
```

> To enable Post Thumbnails, the current theme must include
>   add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); in its functions.php file

Comment: Thanks, I tried that function two different ways. Not sure if I'm using it correctly. At least with my original attempt a link to the image was output, now using this new function I can't get anything to show. Can you please look at the update to the OP and tell me what I'm doing wrong (if you have time). Thanks in advance

Comment: This is what it looks like with my code in the OP http://imgur.com/MIGUEc4 when I use `get__post_thumbnail_id`. When I use get_the_post_thumbnail, I get nothing

Comment: Did you try with only the ech i put in my answer without the `$post_image` thing ?

Comment: yes, I also tried this (without the post_image variable) `echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, 'small', $attr ); . '<br />' . get_the_title() . '</a>';   `  the image is supposed to be displayed above the title, hence the get_the_title() method it's combined with. Image doesn't show when I do this, just the title

Comment: Did you put some images as featured one inthe admin section?